# How to know the rank of list member ?.net

Tags: .net, list

i just have this question:
"Score: give 10 marks if he/she is the first author, 7 marks if he/she is the second, 5 marks if he/she is the third, and 2 marks if he/she is the fourth or more"
so i retrieve the data form table then insert it in list like this.

```
 public int Score2(string auth)
    {
        string S = auth;
        SqlConnection con;
        con = new 
        SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ADP_C1ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Authors FROM Paper WHERE 
        Authors LIKE '%" + auth + "%' ", con);
        List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Mylist.Add(Convert.ToString(dr[0]));
            }
        }
```

and now i need to know the rank of the table data i retrieve to give different mark to each author like this , so nadia will take 5 marks

[image]

any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table data looks like in your image, you could start with a method like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GetScores(string authorsCell)
{
    var scores = new List<int> { 10, 7, 5, 2 };

    // Probably better to use something like List<Tuple<string, int>> since author names may not be unique.
    // I'm using a Dictionary<string, int> here for simplicity.
    var authorScores = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    var authors = authorsCell.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < authors.Length; i++)
    {
        int scoreRank = i;

        if (scoreRank > scores.Count - 1)
        {
            scoreRank = scores.Count - 1;
        }

        int score = scores[scoreRank];

        authorScores.Add(authors[i], score);
    }

    return authorScores;
}
```

The method takes the value of the authors field from the database. You can then use it like this:

```
string authorsCell = "hadi,mohamed,nadia,test1,test2"; // This is your dr[0]

var authorScores = GetScores(authorsCell);
```

This will give you a dictionary with these values (using the sample data), for each row returned by your select:

[image: AuthorsDictionary]

Looking at the return type of your method (`int`) and at the fact that you're selecting data using a `like`, it's not entirely clear what you expect your method to do. Since it's not very clear what your ultimate goal is based on your return type (`int`), I will assume that you want to get the sum of all scores for a given author.

To do that, first declare a dictionary outside your while loop, and then populate it with values from every row from your resultset:

```
var authorScores = new Dictionary<string, int>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    var currentScores = GetScores(dr[0].ToString());

    foreach (var authorScore in currentScores)
    {
        if (authorScores.ContainsKey(authorScore.Key))
        {
            authorScores[authorScore.Key] += authorScore.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            authorScores[authorScore.Key] = authorScore.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

At this stage, say that your query returns 2 rows:

```
hadi,mohamed,nadia,test1,test2
mohamed,nadia,test3
```

After the above code runs, the `authorScores` dictionary will contain the following values:

[image: AuthorsDictionarySums]

And, finally, you can return this from your method:

```
return authorScores[auth]; // auth is your method parameter
```

Now, there are many things that can be improved in your code and my examples (various checks such as `null` checks, `using`s around your `SqlConnection`/`SqlCommand`, etc) but for simplicity, I chose to leave those out.

There may be some issues around your query using a `like`. Say that your query returns 10 rows because the data matches with the `like`. The `authorScores` dictionary will be populated with author names and scores. I'm not sure what author names may look like but, on the final return, if there is no **exact** match for your parameter (`auth`), the method will throw an exception (if, of course you don't add a check to see if `auth` exists in your dictionalry).

Hope this was what you were looking for.